# How to get the rank of an item based on a sort with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working on a leaderboard and my documents have the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566a8ccc5bce504423858ba2"),
    "username" : "John Smith",
    "score" : 123,
}
```

When a player enter his score, I'm looking for an optimized way to show his rank also as the two previous and two next players in the leaderboard.

E. g. If my name is *Bob Dylan*

```
#  Name      Score
10 J. Smith    128
11 M. Collins  126
12 Bob Dylan   120
13 JAKE        113
14 Mikes       110
```

And then my rank is 12.

Do you know how I can get this kind of data?

I'd like to avoid a `.find().sort({ score: -1});` and search the user afterward.

Can I optimize it?

Comment: I think you won't get around querying the users score and then doing two additional queries to get those with a lower and with a higher score respectively, sorted by score limited to two.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **aggregation**. i have done using aggregation. it think it should work for you.

```
db.predictions.aggregate(
      { $sort : {"score" : 1}},
      { $project : { "score":true,
                     "ranking" : { 
                                  "$divide" : ["$score", "$score"]
                                 }
                   }
      },
      { $sort : {"ranking" : 1}})
```